# How to compile multiple csv files into a single xlsx file using R and name each tab after csv file name?

Tags: r, csv

Say I have many csv files in a directory called `Path`:

```
abc.csv
def.csv
xyz.csv
```

How can I compile these files into a single xlsx file where each csv becomes its own tab named after the csv's file name? The below function was recommended from a previous post and works well, I just need the tabs to be named after the right csv:

```
# set wd to appropriate directory
list.files(pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
  map(., ~read_csv(.)) %>% 
  write.xlsx(., "My Multi-tabbed File.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, to name the list elements according to the csv filename (before the `.`), which should then be picked up as the sheet names...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

filelist <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv") 

filelist %>% 
  map(read_csv) %>% 
  set_names(str_remove(filelist, "\\..+")) %>%
  write.xlsx("My Multi-tabbed File.xlsx")
```

Comment: This is great. How would I go about alphabetizing my tabs? Would i just sort my file list alphabetically and then run?

Comment: @R.Baratheon Yes, you could just do `filelist = sort(list.files(...))`